# How do I loop through nested children structure?

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm looking for general solution when we don't know the depth of parenthesisis. However example would be this:

```
<div id="parent">
 <div id="parent_child">
  <div id="parent_child_child">
   <div id="parent_child_child_child">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

How can I loop through such structure in vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: You should add the code you've tried to your question. Don't rely on SO as your personal coding service.

Comment: I can't even figure how to begin. I'm pretty new to programming sorry.

Comment: Find tutorials on basic JS loops and DOM node traversal to begin with.

Comment: I assume you can't rely on that exact DOM structure. If not, then do a search for "walking the DOM" to find out a very general solution for walking all nodes, or if you only need elements, then from your root element, do `.getElementsByTagName("*")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `jQuery` is an option, you can use a `descendant selector` to find all child nodes (at any depth) then use `.each` to iterate over them.

```
$("#parent div").each(function(){
   //your code goes here
});
```

A pure JavaScript solution would be.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#parent div")).forEach(function(itm){
    console.log(itm); //itm represents the individual element.
});
```

- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) will grab the elements based on
  supplied selector.
- [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) will convert a node list to a native array.
- [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) will be handy in iterating over an array.

Comment: Interesting: For those curious, `Array.from` documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: This does actually exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :)

Comment: I wasn't the down voter, but mentioning that `Array.from` is very new to the language and has limited or no support in anything but the latest browsers would be a good addition your answer.

Comment: The question states that he's looking for a general solution, and that the markup given is just an example. Your solution will only work for a DOM like one given in the question, so it isn't useful in other situations.

Comment: @squint I taught him how to iterate over a collection of elements, and how to select elements(querySelectorAll). From this point he can learn further. Also he can pass whatever selector he wants and adapt this code to his situation.

Comment: Does he know how to select all elements irrespective of their tag name? Does he need to include text nodes and/or comment nodes in the traversal? A generalized solution would take those into account.